# Passing SEO friendly title instead of an ID number in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm using `vuejs` with `vue router` and i'm using `axios` to make get requests to an API based on routes i've set up in my router/index.js file.

However I want to pass SEO friendly title instead of the id.

`myname/products/bears` instead of `myname/products/1`

**Route**

```
   {
        path: '/products/:id',
        name: 'productDetail',
        props: true,
        component: function () {
            return import('../views/products/mycomponent')
        }
    },
```

**Methods**

```
getProduct(){
            var itemId = this.$route.params.id;
            //return console.log(itemId)
            axios
            .get('http://localhost:3000/products/'+itemId)
            .then(response => (
                this.server = response.data
            ))
        },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build SEO-friendly routes in NuxtJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61450474/how-to-build-seo-friendly-routes-in-nuxtjs)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I believe this is more of a data issue? If your id were `bears`, it would work as you intend. If your field providing the name `bears` is also unique, you could probably use that in place of the id in the url.

As a side note: VueJS on its own can not provide SEO friendly meta data, you may want to look into using something like Gridsome or Nuxt for that.

Comment: Thanks I could possibly send it then as products/bears/uniqueID